# best practice of UAC: Behavior of the elevation prompt for administrators in Admin Approval Mode

Tags: uac

I found the follwing regarding UAC Behavior of the elevation prompt for administrators in Admin Approval Mode:

> Malware can present an imitation of the secure desktop, but when the User Account Control: Behavior of the elevation prompt for administrators in Admin Approval Mode policy setting is set to Prompt for consent, the malware doesn't gain elevation if the user selects Yes on the imitation. If the policy setting is set to Prompt for credentials, malware imitating the credential prompt may be able to gather the credentials from the user. However, the malware doesn't gain elevated privilege and the system has other protections that mitigate malware from taking control of the user interface even with a harvested password.
>
> Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/application-security/application-control/user-account-control/how-it-works

Does this mean that setting the behavior fro admin in admin approval mode to "Promt for consent" instead of "prompt for credentials" is the best practise?

Answer (score 0):

*Prompt for credentials* is the default for non-administrators elevation. *Prompt for consent for non-Windows binaries* is the default for administrator command prompt elevation. I've never seen a useful and valid reason to change it from the default.

UAC is 15 years old technology. It should have been in place by default years ago, and Microsoft still recommends leaving it enabled. However Microsoft no longer considers UAC to be a significant security boundary. They assume it will be enabled and used for the one feature. I would be surprised if there were still organizations out there that deliberately disable UAC, SecureBoot, TPM, host-based firewalls and the like, although a few are known to exist.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/application-security/application-control/user-account-control/settings-and-configuration

Comment: FTR, I don't believe MS ever stated that UAC was a security boundary; in fact, all I can remember is the opposite (e.g.: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/windows-security/disable-user-account-control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/windows-security/disable-user-account-control)).

Comment: @Bill_Stewart: Microsoft clarified the policy in 2018. Prior to the clarification, several CVEs were assigned for UAC type exploits. The actual "security boundaries" and non-boundary features such as UAC determine what is actionable for the monthly update, or what is relegated to the next semi-annual or annual update. The clarification also addressed items that  were previously ignored or overlooked (the printer potato vulnerabilities) https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/msrc/windows-security-servicing-criteria